# char size confusion

Tags: c++, char, byte, bit

As per I know that 1 char = 1 byte = 8 bits(32 bit system).

```
char c=0xffff0000;  //wrong
```

then why `char` allow just **8 bits** and also every character in a file also of **8 bit** length.

thanks.

Comment: good title to this question, though.

Comment: @Dave18: a byte is not always 8 bits - it just happens to be the most common value these days,

Comment: Since the tag is `c++`, so please refer this link: [Would you please go over the rules about bytes, chars, and characters one more time?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/intrinsic-types#bytes-review).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No. The sizeof char is by definition 1. But this does not mean that it occupies 32-bits/8-bits always.

> $3.9.1/1- "Objects declared as characters (char) shall be large
>   enough to store any member of the
>   implementation’s basic character set."

There appears to be a confusion that a byte is 8-bits. The C++ Standard does not mandate this however.

Here's how byte is defined in the Standard $1.7/1

> The fundamental storage unit in the C
>   + + memory model is the byte. A byte is at least large enough to contain
>   any member of the basic execution
>   character set and is composed of a
>   contiguous sequence of bits, **the
>   number of which is
>   implementation-defined**.

As is clear, a byte need not be always 8-bits.

Comment: Do you know of any system where a byte is not 8 bits? Curious.

Comment: @Steve Townsend: Nope. My programming world starts in late 90s :)

Comment: I've heard that some DSPs have 1 byte of 12 bits (hope I/m not wrong).

Comment: @Steve: "The use of 8-bit codes for digital telephony also caused 8-bit data 'octets' to be adopted as the basic data unit of the early Internet." and more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Size

Comment: @botismarius: Yes, it appears so with TMS320C44 and others. Unfortunately, I haven't got a chance to work with DSPs :(

Answer (score 4):

Just because a system is classified as "32 bit" doesn't mean it uses 32-bit bytes.

A byte is often defined (in a system-dependent way) as the smallest addressable piece of memory, and for many architectures that is still 8 bits, even though the architectures (like x86 or x86-64) are capable of working with larger amounts of data in registers (32 vs 64, respectively). If you're into this thinking, you often use the word "octet" to talk about 8-bit quantities, since the meaning of "byte" changes with the architecture being discussed.

In contrast, for some people "a byte" is defined as always being 8 bits, but then the confusion in the question would probably never happen since they wouldn't expect `char` on e.g. a 32-bit system to be 32 bits.

Of course, the entire idea of classifying a system as "*n*-bit" is oversimplifying things quite a lot.

In C, you can always `#include <limits.h>` and then use the `CHAR_BIT` macro to get the number of bits in the compiler target's `char` data type.

Answer (score 3):

char has `CHAR_BIT` bits  [from `#include <climits>`]

On 80x86 machines I have always seen this as 8-bits.
On a TMS320C54x and TMS320C55x DSP's I have seen it as 16-bit. This was a pain because to save memory, strings had to be packed with two ASCII characters held in each char!

Always, `sizeof(char) == 1`

Answer (score 2):

a char is always a byte and always has size 1.

A byte always has at least 8 bits but can have more on some systems.

A 32-bit system refers to the size of the address-bus, in C or C++ you can think of this as the size of a pointer, not the size of a byte.

Answer (score 1):

The number of bits in a `char` generally 8 (one byte/octet). The exact number is defined in the header `<climits>` as `CHAR_BIT`.

Answer (score 0):

1 byte = 8 bits

Comment: Not necessarily, though almost universal now. The C++ standard caters for computers with 6-bit bytes (as per the quote posted by @Chubsdad).

Comment: @larsmans: Actually, it doesn't.  CHAR_BIT must be at least 8.

Comment: @Fred Nurk: you're right, and I'd miscounted the required character set size in C++. 6,5 bits is the minimum `char` size that will store them :)

Answer (score 0):

One byte is most certainly NOT 32 bits.  A byte is always 8 bits, no matter what system you're on.

A system that is "32-bit" means that the "word" size is 32 bits.  In other words, data is transferred around the system in 32-bit chunks.

Comment: no. a byte as in C++ Standard is not 8-bit always. Refer my answer

Comment: @Chubsdad is right. ISO tends to use the word `octet` for an 8-bit value (at least for the comms-type standards), `byte` and `char` are the same (implementation-defined) size in C++ (and C).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to points made already - note that `sizeof(char)` and the size of a character are not always the same.

Multibyte character sets can take > 1 byte per character - for example, a Unicode character always takes up more than one byte (`sizeof(wchar_t)`).

Microsoft docs on this topic are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z097dxa%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).  To add to the confusion, some character sets don't even use a fixed number of bytes for each character.

Comment: "a Unicode character always takes up two bytes (sizeof(wchar_t)" would suggest that `sizeof(wchar_t)` is always 2. A common value is in fact 4, which makes sense as there are ~100.000 Unicode characters.

Comment: At least it's now in line with normal compilers, but from a standards perspective there's still a few comments to be made. "Multibyte characters" are well-defined in C and C++, but they're not `wchar_t`. Instead, a multi-byte character (MBC) is a sequence of more than one `char`==byte. Shift-JIS or UTF-8 use such characters. And since `wchar_t` is unrelated to multi-byte characters, you can't deduce that `sizeof(wchar_t)` is always >1.