# What is going on in this code?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, endianness

Can somebody please explain the code for me?

Why 32 bit `UINT`?

Why `0xff`?

What are 4 right shifts doing here?

```
int writeUINT32little(FILE *f, UINT32 i)
{    
    int rc;    
    rc = fputc((i & 0xff), f);    
    if (rc == EOF)       return rc;    
    rc = fputc(((i >> 8) & 0xff), f);    
    if (rc == EOF)       return rc;    
    rc = fputc(((i >> 16) & 0xff), f);    
    if (rc == EOF)       return rc;    
    return fputc(((i >> 24) & 0xff), f);
}
```

Comment: This writes a 32-bit unsigned integer to the file in little-endian format.

Comment: Error checking a function that writes to a file. A rare find in a world where even useful error checking is seldom seen.

Comment: Follow up question (for everyone): Can you write that readable *without* using comments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This takes a 32-bit unsigned integer and outputs it to a file, byte-by-byte with the least significant byte first (i.e. little-endian).

`0xff` is the hexadecimal way of writing `255` in decimal, or `11111111` in binary. And `&` is the bitwise `and` function. Put together, `(i & 0xff)` masks out the least significant byte of the integer.

Then the shifts shift the whole thing over 8 bits and the process repeats to print the next byte.

Answer (score 1):

What this function *supposedly* does is write a 32bit unsigned integer to a file stream in little-endian.

What it really does is, instead of doing one small simple task and getting it right, it tries to do two things together and gets both wrong.

Before I go into why this is wrong, I'll quickly answer the question itself:

- Why `UINT32`? Don't know. It's non standard and better be replaced with `uint32_t`.
- Why `0xff`? Used as a mask to keep the lower 8 bits in a larger variable (32 bits)
- What are 4 right shifts doing here? The shifts are used to bring every byte in the original UINT to the rightmost bits in the correct "little-endian" order.

---

Now, with that out of the way...

**Why this is wrong?**
A `char` is guaranteed to be [**at least 8 bits wide**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727465/will-a-char-always-always-always-have-8-bits), but it *could* be larger. This means that `fputc` will probably write 8 bits per call, but it might write more. What this means is that on a certain architecture where a char is (for example) 16 bits, the function will write 64 bits per call and it won't be little-endian at all. Additionally, the function is very careful checking for errors but doesn't expose the relevant failure information to the caller (how many bytes were written?).

**What's a better design?**
First, as always, do one small thing and do it right:

```
uint32_t toLittleEndian(uint32_t v)
{
    uint32_t result = v >> 24;
    result |= v << 24;
    result |= (v >> 8) & 0xf0;
    result |= (v << 8) & 0xf00;
    return result;
}
```

<sub>Note: this implementation is deliberately verbose. There's an optimisation opportunity using bit rotation operations but C has no native support for that and requires assembly code</sub>

This function *only* converts a big-endian 32 bit value to its equivalent little-endian representation (actually it alternates between the two and could be named `switchEndian`).

Next, we need to write the value to a file:

```
int write(uint32_t v, FILE *f)
{
    return fwrite(&v, sizeof(v), 1, f);
}
```

This will write **exactly** 32 bits wide integer, and return the number of bytes actually written. Additionally, it's reusable.

Next, we could create a convenience composite function if we want:

```
int writeLittleEndian(uint32_t v, FILE *f)
{
    return write(toLittleEndian(v), f);
}
```