# C's implicit type conversion

Tags: c, types

```
int main() {
    int a = 100000;
    char b;
    b = a;
}
```

I assumed that this code wouldn't compile, but it does. Could someone give me a solid explanation of how c handles implicit type conversion?

Comment: Everything is here: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3

Comment: My compiler says *"warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'int' to 'char', possible loss of data"*.

Answer (score -1):

C is not type safe. It heavily relies on the user and therefore assumes he knows what he's doing.

This assignment is implementation dependent `ìnt` and will assign the least significant byte to the `char` variable.

Assuming the size of an `int` of your host architecture is 32 bits, and being your `ìnt` by default `signed`, then the range the `ìnt` can store is of

[-1 * (2^(32 - 1) -1) , 2^(32 - 1)] = [-2147483647, 2147483648]

Compare that to the range that an `unsigned char` can store (depends on host architecture but `char` usually being 8-bit long):

[0, 255]

You can think of `char` as being an integer limited to that range. It might get confusing since it is commonly used to store characters.

Comment: If the `char` is signed, and the `int` one can't fit `char` (and it can't given the value), the result will be implementation defined.

Comment: *All what will happen is that this assignment will truncate the `ìnt` value so it can fit in the `char` variable.* No, as @EugeneSh. states,  see http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p3

Comment: *"char always being 8-bit long"* – The C standard does not mandate that, compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727465/will-a-char-always-always-always-have-8-bits (POSIX however does).

Comment: *`char` always being 8-bit long*  Not correct.  Per [**5.2.4.2.1  Sizes of integer types <limits.h>**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1): "Their implementation-defined values shall be **equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value)** to those shown ..."

Comment: To be clear: "... will assign the least significant byte to the char variable." is not specified by C. It is only an ID possibility. The conversion/assignment is "implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised."

Comment: Off by 1 : at least once. `[-1 * (2^(32 - 1) -1) , 2^(32 - 1)] = [-2147483647, 2147483648]` is certainly incorrect.  Integer max values are always a power-of-2 minus 1

Comment: @chux: char is sometimes unsigned.

Comment: @rici True, when `char` is _unsigned_, the conversion/assignment is well defined.  No UB.