# C: Is there something wrong with declaring byte arrays as uint8_t?

Tags: c, arrays, char, uint8t, stdint

I'm working on a small networking application that uses byte arrays. Traditionally these would be declared with something like `char buf[] = ...`.

This seems to be how it is (still?) done in most tutorials, yet it has the problem that it may obscure what is actually happening, for example when you try to print such an array and forget that not every char is a visible character.

Some people [have suggested](https://matt.sh/howto-c) that you should stop using `chars` altogether and instead use the modern `uint8_t`. I find that very appealing, mostly on the principle that explicit is better than implicit.

So, is there something wrong with declaring these kinds of arrays as `uint8_t buf[] = ...`?

Comment: To me it seems nothing is wrong with neither. A char is defined as 8 bits (1 byte) for all platforms, just as `uint8_t`. The only difference/problem with un- or signed is the sign extension when casting or converting to int.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - That (`char` is 8 bits) is not guaranteed.  Overwhelmingly common, yes, but not guaranteed.

Comment: If char is not guaranteed 8 bits (thanks @OliverCharlesworth) then char must be used where char is required and `uint8_t` where bytes are requried (the latter e.g. on a network interface, the former e.g. on character processing).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: But `char` is the "smallest addressable unit" and has at least 8 bits. So *if* there is a `uint8_t` then both have the same size. – (Btw, POSIX requires that CHAR_BIT == 8.)

Comment: If  network code depends on`char`s signedness (or size, or padding) , it is bad code anyway. IMHO.

Comment: @wildplasser network protocols are defined in terms of octets; I think it is reasonable for code to depend on `char` being 8-bit

Comment: Consider looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727465/will-a-char-always-always-always-have-8-bits

Comment: @M.M : exactly. But the wording should be  : char being *at least* 8bits wide.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I should be reading more comprehensive tutorials then:) Thanks everyone!

Comment: `uint8_t` is an optional type. I don't think it can exist if `unsigned char` is not exactly 8 bits wide, because `unsigned char` is the smallest addressable unit, and both `uint8_t` (if it exists) and `unsigned char` have no padding bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with the introduction of [`stdint.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) header in C99, there is no good reason to continue using `char` type to represent small numbers.

In addition to documenting your intentions better, `uint8_t` gives you one more important advantage: it guarantees that the byte is going to be treated as unsigned. When you use `char` you cannot assume if it is signed or unsigned, because this behavior is implementation-defined.

As far as inadvertent printing of the buffer goes, using `uint8_t` is not going to guarantee any protection, because on many platforms it's simply a `typedef` for `unsigned char`.

Comment: `uint8_t` does have the theoretical problem that it might not be a typedef for a character type, and therefore cannot be used for aliasing other types ... I expect that to be fixed at some point in the future though