# Char tab on 3 octets

Tags: c, char, octetstring

I would like to know how to define a char array, in C, of three elements `a,b,c`, where `a` is located on one first octet, `b` in one second and `c` in one third.

Comment: What is a char tab? Do you mean tab as in table, so an array?

Comment: Yes an array, bad translation, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 
In C, the size of *char* it's 1.
I think we can't know if it's 1 octet or more (or less).

So,

```
char tab[3] = {'a','b','c'};
```

doesn't work ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can't be less than 1 octet, given that `CHAR_MIN <= -127` and `CHAR_MAX >= 127` ([C11 5.2.4.2.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1)).

Comment: Sure ! So, it's just 1 octet or more :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727465/will-a-char-always-always-always-have-8-bits.

Comment: Viz, `CHAR_BIT` in `limits.h` should tell you. On all POSIX machines, it's 8.